# Audit trigger inserting multiple rows into audit table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have written a trigger and when I update a value in the base table, I get more than one record in my audit table.  I'm expecting just one.  Here's my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SOP10100_TRDISAMT
ON dbo.SOP10100
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (select TRDISAMT from inserted) = 0
        BEGIN
            RETURN
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @SOPTYPE smallint = (select soptype from inserted)
            DECLARE @SOPNUMBE char(21) = (select sopnumbe from inserted)
            DECLARE @MSTRNUMB int = (select mstrnumb from inserted)
            DECLARE @DOCID char(15) = (select docid from inserted)
            DECLARE @SUBTOTAL numeric(19,5) = (select subtotal from inserted)
            DECLARE @MISCAMT numeric(19,5) = (select MISCAMNT from inserted)
            DECLARE @TRDISAMT numeric(19,5) = (select TRDISAMT from inserted)
            DECLARE @TRDISAMT_B4 numeric(19,5) = (select TRDISAMT from deleted)
            DECLARE @FRTAMNT numeric(19,5) = (select FRTAMNT from inserted)
            DECLARE @TAXAMNT numeric(19,5) = (select TAXAMNT from inserted)
            DECLARE @DOCAMNT numeric(19,5) = (select DOCAMNT from inserted)
            DECLARE @USERNAME nvarchar(128) = (select SUSER_SNAME())
            DECLARE @TheTime datetime = (select GETDATE())

            INSERT INTO SOP10100_TRDISAMT_AUDIT (soptype,sopnumbe,MSTRNUMB,DOCID,SUBTOTAL,MISCAMT,TRDISAMT,TRDISAMT_B4,FRTAMNT,TAXAMNT,DOCAMNT,USERNAME,TheTime)
            VALUES (@SOPTYPE,@SOPNUMBE,@MSTRNUMB,@DOCID,@SUBTOTAL,@MISCAMT,@TRDISAMT,@TRDISAMT_B4,@FRTAMNT,@TAXAMNT,@DOCAMNT,@USERNAME,@TheTime)
        END
    END
```

and here is what I run to update the value:

```
update SOP10100 set TRDISAMT = 35 where SOPTYPE = 1 and SOPNUMBE = '126535'
```

This results in two records being inserted into my audit table.  Thoughts?

Comment: Your trigger is *flawed*, it assumes an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` only ever effects 1 row; this is simply not true. A Trigger can effect 0+ rows.

Comment: Also the above won't `INSERT` 2 rows, on;y 1.

Comment: [**The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers**](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) You are not taking into account multiple rows in the `inserted` table. And your particular example will only reproduce if you execute the update twice. But what are you trying to do: what happens if someone updates a row to the same values? Or updates the row but not the  `TRDISAMT` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your query is fatally flawed, because it does not take into account multiple (or zero) rows being inserted or updated.**

Your trigger should probably look something like this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SOP10100_TRDISAMT
ON dbo.SOP10100
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 

INSERT INTO SOP10100_TRDISAMT_AUDIT
    (soptype, sopnumbe, MSTRNUMB, DOCID, SUBTOTAL, MISCAMT, TRDISAMT,
    TRDISAMT_B4, FRTAMNT, TAXAMNT, DOCAMNT, USERNAME, TheTime)
SELECT i.soptype, i.sopnumbe, i.mstrnumb, i.docid, i.subtotal, i.MISCAMNT, i.TRDISAMT,
    i.TRDISAMT, i.FRTAMNT, i.TAXAMNT, i.DOCAMNT, SUSER_SNAME(), GETDATE()
FROM inserted i
WHERE i.TRDISAMT <> 0;

GO
```

- If you want to exclude rows where the values have not been changed at all by the `UPDATE` statement, you need to add

```sql
EXCEPT
SELECT d.soptype, d.sopnumbe.....
FROM deleted d
```

- I note that `char` is an unusual data type, and should only be used where the value is fixed at that length, otherwise you will get trailing spaces.